# IOS- XMPP - Authenticate and alertview on login button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

Currently i am working on `XMPP` protocol in ios for chatting application. i want to put alert view and authentication on Login button. if authentication will successful then user can see homescreen screen else alert view will appear **please check username and password** i show **chat secure** open source project but i can't understand.

```
//appdelegate.m file .//
- (BOOL)connect
{
if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
    return YES;
   // isauthenticate=YES;
}
  NSString *myJID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyJID];
NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyPassword];

//
// If you don't want to use the Settings view to set the JID,
// uncomment the section below to hard code a JID and password.
//
// myJID = @"user@gmail.com/xmppframework";
// myPassword = @"";

if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
    return NO;
}

[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
password = myPassword;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                        message:@"See console for error details."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);

    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
- (void)disconnect
{
 [self goOffline];
 [xmppStream disconnect];
}

#pragma mark UIApplicationDelegate

 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
DDLogError(@"The iPhone simulator does not process background   network traffic. "
           @"Inbound traffic is queued until the keepAliveTimeout:handler: fires.");
#endif

if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:)])
{
    [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{

        DDLogVerbose(@"KeepAliveHandler");

        // Do other keep alive stuff here.
    }];
}
}

 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
  {
     DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
  }

  - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
 {
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    [self teardownStream];
 }

          #pragma mark XMPPStream Delegate

    - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketDidConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket
  {
     DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
  }

 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings
 {
   DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

   NSString *expectedCertName = [xmppStream.myJID domain];
   if (expectedCertName)
  {
    settings[(NSString *) kCFStreamSSLPeerName] = expectedCertName;
   }

if (customCertEvaluation)
{
    settings[GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust] = @(YES);
}
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveTrust:(SecTrustRef)trust
completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL shouldTrustPeer))completionHandler
{
  DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

   // The delegate method should likely have code similar to this,
   // but will presumably perform some extra security code stuff.
  // For example, allowing a specific self-signed certificate that is known to the app.

  dispatch_queue_t bgQueue =    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{

    SecTrustResultType result = kSecTrustResultDeny;
    OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &result);

    if (status == noErr && (result == kSecTrustResultProceed || result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified)) {
        completionHandler(YES);
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(NO);
    }
   });
  }

  - (void)xmppStreamDidSecure:(XMPPStream *)sender
  {
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
   }

  - (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);


isXmppConnected = YES;

NSError *error = nil;

if (![[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error])
{
    DDLogError(@"Error authenticating: %@", error);
}
}

  - (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender

{
  isauthenticate=YES;

DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

[self goOnline];
}

 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}
```

i have tried with setting `BOOL(isauthenticate)` in `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate` method but not success. i can redirect to homepage but if i wrote wrong detail still it will redirect to homepage. i want to set it if username or password are wrong and did not authenticate by server.

```
     //view controller.m file //
  #import "ViewController.h"
 #import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface ViewController ()<MBProgressHUDDelegate>
{
  MBProgressHUD *HUD;

  IBOutlet UITextField *mViewEmail;
  IBOutlet UITextField *mViewPassword;
 }

@end

 NSString *const kXMPPmyJID = @"kXMPPmyJID";
 NSString *const kXMPPmyPassword = @"kXMPPmyPassword";



 @implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)checkLogin:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"Email: %@  Password: %@",mViewEmail.text,mViewPassword.text);
[self setField:mViewEmail forKey:kXMPPmyJID];
[self setField:mViewPassword forKey:kXMPPmyPassword];


 // if (appdelegate.connect==YES) {


  if([ [self appDelegate] connect])    {



  //  if (appdelegate.isauthenticate==YES) {



    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES] ;
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    HUD.labelText = @"Please Wait";
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    //  HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Close chat";


   [self showHome];

    //}


  }
 //}
 else
 {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                    message:@"Please Check Username or Password"
                                                   delegate:nil   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}

 }

 - (void)showHome{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signIn" sender:self];
 }
```

Comment: you have not set any XMPP delegate, set Delegate then it will invoke delegate methods otherwise not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok. so finaly my problem is solved. and i am posting my answer. first of all my mistake is i forgot to write

```
   appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   appdelegate.viewController = self; // very imp when you call method in app delegate.h
```

in my view controller. so when i call viewcontroller's method in appdelegate it call's but do not execute due to above method is missing (Second line). and then i have call view controller's segue method in **- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender** method. and then work perfectly. so my final solution is

```
    //app delegate.m file//
   - (BOOL)connect
  {
    // Setup HUD(Activity Indicator) when Connect method call //

 HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:HUD];
[HUD setDetailsLabelText:@"Please wait..."];
[HUD setDimBackground:YES];
[HUD setOpacity:0.5f];
[HUD show:YES];

if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
    return YES;
}

NSString *myJID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyJID];
NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyPassword];


if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
    return NO;
}

[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
password = myPassword;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
{
    HUD.hidden=YES;
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                           message:@"See console for error details."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);

    return NO;

 }

  return YES;
 }

 - (void)disconnect
  {
  [self goOffline];
  [xmppStream disconnect];
  }

#pragma mark UIApplicationDelegate

  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
 {


DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

  #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  DDLogError(@"The iPhone simulator does not process background network traffic. "
           @"Inbound traffic is queued until the keepAliveTimeout:handler: fires.");
   #endif

   if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:)])
   {
    [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{

        DDLogVerbose(@"KeepAliveHandler");

        // Do other keep alive stuff here.
      }];
    }
   }

  - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

[self teardownStream];
 }

  #pragma mark XMPPStream Delegate


  - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketDidConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket
 {
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
  }

 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings
  {
  DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

   NSString *expectedCertName = [xmppStream.myJID domain];
 if (expectedCertName)
 {
    settings[(NSString *) kCFStreamSSLPeerName] = expectedCertName;
 }

 if (customCertEvaluation)
 {
    settings[GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust] = @(YES);
 }
}


   - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveTrust:(SecTrustRef)trust
  completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL shouldTrustPeer))completionHandler
  {
      DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);


    dispatch_queue_t bgQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{

    SecTrustResultType result = kSecTrustResultDeny;
    OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &result);

    if (status == noErr && (result == kSecTrustResultProceed || result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified)) {
        completionHandler(YES);
     }
     else {
        completionHandler(NO);
    }
  });
}

  - (void)xmppStreamDidSecure:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
 }

  - (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
 {
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);


   isXmppConnected = YES;

   NSError *error = nil;

  if (![[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error])
  {
      DDLogError(@"Error authenticating: %@", error);
  }
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender

 {
      HUD.hidden=YES; //Hud Will be hide when User Authenticated


     DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
     [self.viewController showHome];  // view controllers method to go to next view controller //

[self goOnline];
}

   - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
// HUD will be hidden and alertview will be shown //

 HUD.hidden=YES;
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                message:@"Please Check Username or Password"
                                               delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];


 isauthenticate=NO;
 DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
 {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
 }

}
```

and in  viewcontroller.m we have show that viewcontroller is also appdelegate controller. so we have to declare it in **- (void)viewDidLoad** method.

```
// viewcontroller.m file//
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
    appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   appdelegate.viewController = self;
  }

 - (AppDelegate *)appDelegate
 {
  return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 }

    - (IBAction)checkLogin:(id)sender {
     [self dismissKeyboard];
     NSLog(@"Email: %@  Password: %@",mViewEmail.text,mViewPassword.text);
     [self setField:mViewEmail forKey:kXMPPmyJID];
     [self setField:mViewPassword forKey:kXMPPmyPassword];

     [[self appDelegate ]connect];//call when loginbutton pressed 

      }

     //call in appdelegate.h // segue(push) to next view

     - (void)showHome
      {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signIn" sender:self];
       }
```

**Note:** I have tried to explain as much as i can.

Answer (score 1):

If username and password are correct then xmppStreamDidAuthenticate method call and if one of them is incorrect then didNotAuthenticate method call.

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
}

 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}
```

Here print error and display this error in UIALertview as you required.

Comment: this method does not work because xmpp stream takes times to authenticate the user. after call connect method  so may be i have to set HUD with timer "Activity indicator" but i dont know how to setup this whole things. need suggetion or method. thanks.

Comment: There is one methods name goonline. So after success authenticate this methods goonline call. So if you have to do any operation you can start spin (indicator/SVProgress) and in goonline method dismiss svprogress. and you can navigate to home view as you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot .i can understand your answer. so now in login method how to set indicator that wait till go online method execute.?

Comment: You have to put indicator in setupStream method and dismiss in goonline method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are checking `XMPP` connection that is not means `Authenticate User`. if your **User Name** and password is correct then you received response in `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate` method. where you can write the code to push to HomeViewController once user is verified.

Below two methods, you can used to show alert or push to another view once user varified.

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender

{

}

 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

this is `XMPP` Delegate methods

Hope this help you.

Comment: i have tried this but not success. we have must call connect method on login button then i call method in xmppstreamdidauthenticate. and set alertview on didnotauthenticate. but not succesful.

Comment: you need to set Delegate of XMPP. then XMPP will automatically called its delegate methods. just you need to pass user name and password for varification.